# Change rowsource with a variable in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change the rowsource with a variable from a button click

I have this:

```
Option explicit
Public i as integer

Private Sub cmdMonth_Click()
i=1
call GetMonth
endsub

Private Sub GetMonth()
Me.lstIncome.RowSource = "GetChosenIncome" + "i"
end sub
```

This doesn't work I get "Could not set the rowsource property, invalid property value"

The rowsources are defined in the Name Manager

I appreciate any help

Comment: Putting `"i"` in speech marks means that it is a string and not the value of the `i` variable so you probably want to lose the speech marks ... but then `i` always has the value `1` (one) anyway which is also unlikely to be what you really want. Maybe try to give more detail as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to connect the rowsource GetChosenIncome1 to a listbox. I have 12 different rowsources GetChosenIncome1-GetChosenIncome12. So depending on what button is clicked the variable will be one number from 1 to 12.

Comment: It works if I put in the value of the variable by my self ex "GetChosenIncome"&"1" or "GetChosenIncome"+"1"

Comment: What about `Me.lstIncome.RowSource = ThisWorkbook.Names("GetChosenIncome" & i).Range.Address(External:=True)`? Share more information so we can try to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Its solved like this

```
Option explicit
public i as string (Changed from integer to string)

Private Sub cmdMonth_Click()
i="1" (added quote marks)
call GetMonth
endsub

Private Sub GetMonth()
Me.lstIncome.RowSource = "GetChosenIncome" + i (Deleted quote marks)
end sub
```

Thanks helping, you put me on the right track.

Comment: Note: In VBA, You should always use `&` as string concatenation character, not the `+`

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate a string with a variable can be done in this way

```
Me.lstIncome.RowSource = "GetChosenIncome" & i
```

Comment: Same problem doesnt work

Comment: Break your code after assigning and check Rowsource value.